# Block EmailMessage in before trigger

Tags: trigger, email, email2case

I am writing a before insert trigger on EmailMessage object to block emails if the `fromAddress` is in a list of email addresses I have put together. I'm not quite sure on what to set so that the email is never delivered to salesforce. I want to essentially bounce/delete the email so that it doesn't trigger any code. I tried to delete the email by setting `email.IsDeleted = true;`but that field is not writable. Any ideas?

Comment: not sure about this and need to try this out but did you try throwing a custom exception?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using On Demand Email to Case, you can configure disallowed email domains/email addresses as shown here in the Email to Case settings under your routing address

[image]

Alternatively, you can configure your own mail server to block incoming emails from `evildomain.com` sent to `support@mycompany.com`

By the time the trigger on `EmailMessage` is invoked, the Case SObject is created.  I'm not sure if SFDC inserts the Case in the same transaction as it inserts the EmailMessage but if it does (see debug log), you could use `addError()` to cause the transaction to fail - however, you may see sysad messages indicating transaction failures that you'll have to filter out after-the-fact.

Another option I've seen done on SFSE is an After Insert `EmailMessage` trigger that deletes the parent Case if the source `EmailMessage` is from `evildomain.com`.

But, best to block the message before your application ever sees it.

Comment: I can't use the "Accept Email From" feature because I don't know who it is I'm accepting the email from. I need a way to do this with apex

Comment: I gave you a couple of suggestions above for apex as well